# Something lost in translation regarding returning money in this conversation

Tags: conversations

I want to confirm a few things here

> A「はいはい、わかったよ。ホントにいつでもいいから、気が向いたときに返してくれ」(B is insisting that she will definitely return the money ~50k yen)
>
> B「今、その……気持ちだけでも！　今はええっと……三千と、一円ならあるよ！」
>
> A もしかして俺が貸した金、まだ手をつけてないのか？
>
> A「いいよ、ホント。自分の金は大事にしまっとけって」
>
> B「じゃあ一円……？」
>
> A 「いやいらねーから！」
>
> B 「一円玉だって、コツコツ貯めれば結構貯まるもん！」

A:  ok ok, i get it, its all good, return it whenever you can/feel like it

B:  want to return some now , i got... 3k and 1 yen ? (i'm not sure how to read 気持ちだけでも here)

A(internally):  could it be, she hasn't spent any of the money i lent her yet? (then how does she only have 3001 yen?)

A:   its fine, really, take care of your own money.

B:   then how about  1 yen...

A:   NO, not needed

B: even if it's one yen (at a time?),  if i diligently save, I'll save alot (at this point i know i've lost something from  the 三千と、一円ならあるよ line but i don't know what it is)

I'm probably not reading 今、その……気持ちだけでも！　今はええっと……三千と、一円ならあるよ！ right, but can't pin it down.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

気持ち can mean "a little something to show my feeling/honesty/gratitude". For example, [気持ちばかりのものですが](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B0%97%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C) and [気持ちです](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/12637/) are humble set phrases you can use when you present something. In this context, 気持ちだけでも means "(although the amount of money is small,) I at least want to show the will to return the money (by paying a part of the debt now)!"

Comment: Ah that would make more sense since she  definitely  didn't already spend all the money.